# Send to back ActiveX button

Tags: excel, vba

I got group of ActiveX buttons (small keyboard) and it looks like this:
[image: keyboard]

Everything is ok, but when I miss click any button and I just click button on the background (*button_back*), this button will bring on top:
[image]

Only when I move pointer out of the button, other keys appears.
I want to disable button in the background in a way that nothing happens when it's clicked.
I tired:
- **button_back.Enabled = False**
- **button_back.SendToBack**
- **.bringToFront** the rest of the buttons
- **button_back.TakeFocusOnClick = False**

I also tried replace ActiveX with Shapes. I have no idea hot to do non clickable background for keyboard.

Comment: Note that a workbook is not a userform. Use Userforms for that. Also don't misuse button as design elements (remove that button in background) and you don't run into such odd issues. • Also I recommend to stay away from ActiveX if possible. FormControls are the better choice.

Comment: Thanks, i will do it with userform

Comment: Agree with @Pᴇʜ Userform is the way to go. Also agree on ActiveX. You will run into all kinds of little issues depeding on what you want to do or on which version of excel and office it runs.